# "You and your X, your Y, your Z that comes...". Why is the verb in singular form?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, relative-clauses

The third sentence in the book Packing for Mars is:

> You and your fluctuating metabolism, your puny memory, your frame that comes in a million different configurations.

Why is the verb (*come*) in singular form, when there are four subjects? What is the role of *that* in this case?

Comment: Because the subject is **frame**.  The puny memory doesn't come in a million different configurations, and neither does the metabolism.  *You and your bling, your diamond eyeglasses, your big rings, your golden chains that hang around your tatted throat.*

Comment: So this is not a full sentence with verbs, but just listing things and that's all?

Comment: *You and your questions!*  It is an exclamation. A form of address, and an implied remark.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I see. If the sentence is to be written as normal, what would it be?

Comment: It does not make an explicit predication. There is no way to write it "as normal". It  could express exasperation, contempt, impatience, humor, delight, fatigue, almost any emotion or mental state.